# Swagger works with @RepositoryRestController

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-web

I need your help with a interesting problem:
I want to use swagger for easy API Documentation and I got two classes: a versionController and a PersonController. The version controller has 2 annotations:

```
- @RestController
- @Requestmapping(value = "/version")
```

While the person controller has one annotation on top:

```
-@RepositoryRestController
```

And has the following annotation on the create Person Method:

```
-@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/persons")
-@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

My question is this. Why is versionController visible in swagger and is PersonController not? I mean, personcontroller has the mappings right, so swagger can 'see' it? The source documentation didn't had any information on it, so I hope you guys/girls can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Greetings,
Frederick

Comment: Are you using Springfox or something else to generate your Swagger documentation?  I am going to guess that the issue is that `@RepositoryRestController` is not picked up as a Controller annotation, since it does not itself contain the `@Controller` annotation, whereas `@RestController` does.

Comment: I am using springfox woelmer, And what you said sounds reasonble, however, I was wondering if it's possible somehow to generate the swagger documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you.  This seems like something Springfox should support, though, so I'd suggest asking the devs about it: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues

Comment: Then I shall ask the developers, anyway, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

4 years later, in Springfox, support is still missing for @RepositoryRestController.

See this issue - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2656

A workaround is to use both @RepositoryRestController and @RestController annotations on the controller class.